# SweetAlert with Bootstrap nav tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, sweetalert

I have a bootstrap nav tab with 4 links (Applicant, Coverages, Locations, Premium).  I have a jquery click event on Coverages to validate the Applicant data.  If failed, display sweetalert and stay on the Applicant tab:

```
$('#CoveragesTab').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    SaveApplicantTabData(function (retVal) {
        if ("success" == retVal.status) {
        }
        else if ("failed" == retVal.status) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            swal(retVal.message, "Applicant Error", "error");
            //alerta(retVal.message);
            return false;
        }
        else if ("error" == retVal.status) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            alert(retVal.message);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Functionally, this works perfectly, but the Coverages link looks like it still has the focus - the whole square of the tab is highlighted the same as hovering over a tab.  It doesn't have the focus.  I checked with developer tools and the active link is correct as well as other values.

How can I remove the focused look from the tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally figured it out.  I have to use both event.stopImmediatePropogation and .blur().

```
$('#CoveragesTab').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    SaveApplicantTabData(function (retVal) {
        if ("success" == retVal.status) {
        }
        else if ("failed" == retVal.status) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('#CoveragesTab').blur();
            swal(retVal.message, "Applicant Error", "error");
            return false;
        }
        else if ("error" == retVal.status) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            alert(retVal.message);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The only thing is that when you use stoppropogation, it leaves the href as part of the url:

```
http://localhost:3858/CreateQuote/EditQuote/1#coverages-tab
```

So I have to strip the quote id from the url.

Does anyone know how to keep this from happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `blur()` method to your `Coverages` nav tab link when validation failes:

```
$('#CoveragesTab').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    SaveApplicantTabData(function (retVal) {
        if ("success" == retVal.status) {
        }
        else if ("failed" == retVal.status) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            swal(retVal.message, "Applicant Error", "error");
            //alerta(retVal.message);
            $(this).blur();
            return false;
        }
        else if ("error" == retVal.status) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            alert(retVal.message);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I also tried $(this).focus().  No luck.  But thank you!

Comment: I also just tried $("#ApplicantLink").addClass('active');

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  Don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Look at this example and try to click Profile. http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/woYGVE

Comment: No luck.  Everything already worked when using the standard alert box, but not with SweetAlert.  Using that is what's causing the issue.

Comment: What version of SweetAlert do you use?

Comment: If you are using version 2, look at the previous codepen again.

Comment: 1.1.3.  That's the latest from NuGet.  I also just noticed that when I use just

Comment: I noticed that if I don't use an ajax call then everything is fine, but when I use the ajax call, that's when the Coverages tab still looks like it has the focus.

Comment: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/blob/master/dist/sweetalert-dev.js You can change line 164 and 230 (change focus to blur) and you are good to go.

Comment: I changed $(this).blur() to be more specific $('#CoveragesTab') - the element that has the same href property.